# How can I find records where a field appears once in a column or multiple times in the column but only once between a set of dates?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query that brings up the details (invoiceNumber, name, phone & email) from a table but only where the entries match these specific requirements:

Return the rows where the email address appears only once in the whole table from any date
AND
Return the rows where the email address multiple times WHERE the email has only been entered ONCE within the last 3 months.

I am fairly sure that this requires nested statements but I have no idea how to go about setting it up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First of all we will need a means of being able to tell if the email address has been entered in the last few months. Do you have a timestamp column or something similar? It would be useful if you could provide a little sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach this by thinking about the email addresses.  You can determine the frequency of appearance by doing a group by:

```
      select emailaddress, count(*) as TotalCnt,
             sum(case when invoicedate >= sysdate - 90 then 1 else 0 end) as LastThreeMonths
      from t
      group by emailaddress;
```

This gives you the information you need.  The following query joins this back to the original table to get the rows you are looking for:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select emailaddress, count(*) as TotalCnt,
             sum(case when invoicedate >= sysdate - 90 then 1 else 0 end) as LastThreeMonths
      from t
      group by emailaddress
     ) e
     on t.emailaddress = e.emailaddress
where e.TotalCnt = 1 or e.LastThreeMonths = 1
```